# How to do value_counts based on value in another dataframe column python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two pandas dataframe like

```
data1 = [[s1, 0], [s2, 0], [s3, 1], [s4, 1], [s5, 0], [s6, 1], [s7, 0], [s8, 1]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['s_no', 'values']) 

data2 = [[s1, 0], [s2, 1], [s3, 1], [s4, 0], [s5, 0], [s6, 1], [s7, 1], [s8, 0]] 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['s_no2', 'values2'])
```

How to find the value_counts of

```
df2['values2'].value_counts() when df1['values'] == 1 and 

df2['values2'].value_counts() when df1['values'] == 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First is necessary same index values and size in both `DataFrame`s, so possible join togehter, and then is possible use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Advatage is possible check if correct aligned, if data for next processing are like you need.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df)
  s_no  values s_no2  values2
0   s1       0    s1        0
1   s2       0    s2        0
2   s3       1    s3        1
3   s4       1    s4        1
4   s5       0    s5        0
5   s6       1    s6        1
6   s7       0    s7        0
7   s8       1    s8        1

print (df.loc[df['values'] == 1, 'values2'].value_counts())
1    4
Name: values2, dtype: int64

print (df.loc[df['values'] == 0, 'values2'].value_counts())
0    4
Name: values2, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('values')['values2'].value_counts())
values  values2
0       0          4
1       1          4
Name: values2, dtype: int64
```

Or is possible filter with `df1, df2` - but here is not so easy checking, if something wrong with data:

```
print (df2.loc[df1['values'] == 1, 'values2'].value_counts())
1    4
Name: values2, dtype: int64

print (df2.loc[df1['values'] == 0, 'values2'].value_counts())
0    4
Name: values2, dtype: int64

print (df2['values2'].groupby(df1['values']).value_counts())
values  values2
0       0          4
1       1          4
Name: values2, dtype: int64
```